How would artificial gravity panels affect spaceship design?
Assuming these are panels that can be plastered anywhere that would be convenient, how would spaceship design change?
Would every wall be covered with them so it's all effectively floor space?
Would there need to be special considerations for how the added gravity interacts with whatever propulsion system the ship uses?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need to tell us how these panels work for us to evaluate the impact on spaceship design.

How strong are the panels, and what region do they affect? And how expensive are they to make and maintain, and what are the power reqs? There is a lot of missing information.

How do the panels even work?
Lets assume the most naive idea, that the grav panel is basically a very big floor tile that attracts mass to its "top" side with a vertical vector that runs at a perfectly right angle to the surface of the panel.
Basically, what is above the panel is attracted to it. Things below the panel are not. Things sideways to the panel, even by a millimeter, are not.
Basically, above each panel, there is a theoretically infinite column in which things fall down on the panel, but its potency decreases with distance.
(DISCLAIMER: all of the above is absolutely silly, but this is the only way to have grav-panels that, aside from flagrantly disregarding physics, would not become an impossible engineering headache. Its impossible to have artificial gravity that does not violate physics, but lets alt least have one that conforms to basic common sense.)
So for simplicity's sake, lets assume the grav-panels are 1x1 meter, 1cm thick, and that anything in a realistic distance above them falls on them.
Therefore the most rational design, is to have the spaceship be a long tower, square in cross-section, with its bottom-most floor being covered in grav-panels, while the floors above the panels need not be. This way, most of the ship would be under 1g.
It might make sense to have the guts of the ship (engine, reactor etc) be below the grav-panels, "in the basement" so that they are in 0g (or not, this depends on how the engine and reactor works).
Another thing would be to have a "shaft" going through the ship that has no grav plate at the bottom, so that people and stuff could float up and down it in gentle freefall.
I would not risk putting panels on the walls, especially not opposite to one another. Intersecting gravity fields would play merry hell with the hull structure, and give everyone roller-coaster levels of vertigo, there is not need for that. You want the gravity to go one way and feel seamless between panels, otherwise your crew is going to vomit all over the carpet.
Now the trillion dollar question is: How much power do your grav panels need? And the multi trillion dollar question is, how powerful can you make them?
The reason I'm asking is that if you have artificial gravity plates that need less energy than they can create by making stuff fall down, yo do not need an engine or a reactor. You now have a device that can create its own energy out of nothing, and propel the ship at relativistic speeds. If you can turn a sequence of grav panels quickly one after another, and you stacked them so that their apparent grav field is substantial you can make the whole ship "fall" towards expelled bits of propellant, always missing it.
The same "multi-panel gravity" could very well be used as a weapon, maneuvering thruster (or rather, "puller") and a way to redirect enemy projectiles.

It's the OP who must define how their panel works. By giving this answer you have now forced your interpretation down their throat

Why a vertical structure? Only because it requires fewer panels? but it will need elevators or ladders, making moving around the ship more difficult.

@vsz think about what happens when the ship is under acceleration.

@StarfishPrime : in space why must a spaceship accelerate in the direction of its smallest diameter? There is no need to be aerodynamic. Hey, if the acceleration is really strong, it's better to spread the thrusters across a greater surface.

Downvoted because this answer is thinking inside a gravity well. Floors, Towers ? The craft would be a sphere not a tower for the obvious reason to maximum usable space with minimal surface area. since the panels can be switched off, they can be used on all internal surfaces, meaning up and down are whatever is most convenient in that space at that time.

Two ways to make them less bonkers:  1)  Grav panels are two panels, they exert a gravity field between them, but not extending beyond.  2)  It's basically a charge.  The panels just take parasitic power sitting there, they draw actual power equal to whatever work the field does.  (Or waste it as heat when it does negative work--something gets lifted up.)

@PaulSmith A sphere with grav panels on the walls would have gravity vectors intersect with one another. It would be absolute hell to be in one, like living in a tumble-dryer, or a spin-grav device that went bonkers..

@LorenPechtel Im confused with your design. If two grav plates are opposite to one another, all you achieve is an apparent null point between them, in which an object is equally falling in both directions. In effect, you would only have normal gravity next to the plates, and progressively weaker (apparent) gravity the closer to the middle of the ship.

@StarfishPrime a tower-ship means you need fewer grav panels to put the whole ship under gravity. Gravity goes through the floors no problem, so one plate at the bottom can pull at a thousand floors above it. A tower shaped ship would be also easier to make modular, dock for repairs, or sealed in case of a catastrophic hull breach.

@L.Dutch I am aware, but without that, the question would be unanswerable. And really, gravity panels introduce so many "fridge logic" problems into the setting, that I think the option I described is the least absurd. Any other option I can think of would violate physics even worse, and most importantly, introduce obvious engineering challenges that OP would have to solve. IMHO, the best solution to artificial gravity in a setting is just "assume it works, and do not think about it too closely", otherwise it becomes an impossible headache for the writer.

@GoingDurden I think perhaps you should have directed that comment at vsz, who hasn't thought very hard about acceleration vectors, rather than me.

@GoingDurden You're looking at my design backwards.  The field only exists between them, anything else is in free fall (assuming the ship is not otherwise accelerating.)  Think of it like a giant capacitor (which generates a uniform electric field between it's plates), except with gravity.  And you decidedly would not want one plate with a thousand floors in between--that would cause all the engineering headaches of a 1000-story building.

@LorenPechtel Im not sure how would that work. If there is a pair of plates, do both of them "pull" with gravity, or one somehow "pushes" with antigravity? If they both pull, then the middle point is null gravity, and their gravity extends beyond each other. If one is some kind of reverse gravity the the whole setting needs to be rewritten completely, because anti-grav makes half of the tropes pointless.

@GoingDurden Normal gravity is omnidirectional.  I'm saying plates that are completely directional, the field extends (linearly, because it's not diverging) until it hits the opposite plate.  Think of a capacitor--there's a linear electric field between the plates of a capacitor.  I'm picturing the same thing with gravity.  Nothing in physics suggests it can be done, but it's nowhere near as worldbreaking as a straight up gravity generator would be.

Tiny, Variable Panels
If you make your panels small - think mosaic tiles - and put them on little pivot joints, you can turn every passageway into an automated people mover.
Your crew-members step into the hallway, and state their destination, and the hallway carefully angles and energizes a bunch of panels on the ceiling and walls and floor to redefine "down" as towards your destination. You fall all the way to where ever you are going. (if you start closer to the floor, the ship knows to put more power into the ceiling panels. Once you are in the middle of the hallway, power from all sides is evened out.)
Probably most hallways are zero gee except when a person is transiting them. Express hallways can have the panel direction fixed, so you can only "fall" in one direction - say fore to aft or vice versa. Maybe most travel along the spine of the ship is express, and traveling radially uses more flexible hallways.
Expanding the Thought
Moving cargo around is probably just like the flexible hallways, only you use a bigger space. The cargo hold has lots of mid-size, variable panels and you probably don't actually put things on the "floor." Instead, you use the variable gravity to pull it to where you want, and then use a lattice of steel struts to hold it in place.
Missile launchers, fighter launches, and even kinetic energy weapons can be a variation on the express passage idea. Stuff only moves one way down those particular paths.
The key here is that there's no such thing as a fixed "down." If you can control gravity, down is where ever you want it to be at that moment.

the only problem I see with your idea, is that using gravity to pull people in various directions will play merry hell with their inner ear. You would be giving them vertigo. You would have to give the crew futuristic anti-vertigo meds, or genetically engineer them to be able to handle sudden equilibrioception shifts.
But if you can do that, why bother at all with grav plates? Just engineer them to function in zero G and you're done.
